# AWS ECS Error: Task failed ELB health checks in target-group

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, rust-rocket

I am deploying a compose docker to AWS ECS. The compose contains two services: one postgres and our api running on port 8000.

```
$ compose-ecs up
ApiService ServiceSchedulerInitiated: Task failed ELB health checks in (target-group arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:821470956622:targetgroup/laclie-ApiTC-HTNTTIBU9DVM/03d34a43d358c4b5)
```

compose.yaml

```
services:
  api:
    image: outsidethecode/la-client-api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000" # Map API app port to host
    depends_on:
      - database # Make sure the API app starts after the database is ready
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: "postgresql://postgres:postgres@database/laclient"
      ROCKET_ADDRESS: 0.0.0.0 
      ROCKET_ENV: release

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - api

  database:
    image: postgres:latest # Use the official PostgreSQL image
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: laclient
    ports:
      - "5432:5432" # Map PostgreSQL port to host
```

As to my understanding, to pass the health check we have to have a GET / resource to return 200. I've done that but that resource is on port 8000 similar to the rest of api resources.

Here is the convert version of the cloudformation:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  ApiService:
    DependsOn:
    - ApiTCP8000Listener
    - DatabaseService
    Properties:
      Cluster:
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - Cluster
        - Arn
      DeploymentConfiguration:
        MaximumPercent: 200
        MinimumHealthyPercent: 100
      DeploymentController:
        Type: ECS
      DesiredCount: 1
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      LoadBalancers:
      - ContainerName: api
        ContainerPort: 8000
        TargetGroupArn:
          Ref: ApiTCP8000TargetGroup
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
          SecurityGroups:
          - Ref: DefaultNetwork
          Subnets:
          - subnet-0bd97383cdf4d5896
          - subnet-0a52cf89f7c027b20
          - subnet-0ffafc731067a7d01
          - subnet-0de9ebed3a873fccf
          - subnet-00ae1e792af0e2e1d
          - subnet-0095a287059d86962
      PlatformVersion: 1.4.0
      PropagateTags: SERVICE
      SchedulingStrategy: REPLICA
      ServiceRegistries:
      - RegistryArn:
          Fn::GetAtt:
          - ApiServiceDiscoveryEntry
          - Arn
      Tags:
      - Key: com.docker.compose.project
        Value: laclientapi
      - Key: com.docker.compose.service
        Value: api
      TaskDefinition:
        Ref: ApiTaskDefinition
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
  ApiServiceDiscoveryEntry:
    Properties:
      Description: '"api" service discovery entry in Cloud Map'
      DnsConfig:
        DnsRecords:
        - TTL: 60
          Type: A
        RoutingPolicy: MULTIVALUE
      HealthCheckCustomConfig:
        FailureThreshold: 1
      Name: api
      NamespaceId:
        Ref: CloudMap
    Type: AWS::ServiceDiscovery::Service
  ApiTCP8000Listener:
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
      - ForwardConfig:
          TargetGroups:
          - TargetGroupArn:
              Ref: ApiTCP8000TargetGroup
        Type: forward
      LoadBalancerArn:
        Ref: LoadBalancer
      Port: 8000
      Protocol: TCP
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
  ApiTCP8000TargetGroup:
    Properties:
      Port: 8000
      Protocol: TCP
      Tags:
      - Key: com.docker.compose.project
        Value: laclientapi
      TargetType: ip
      VpcId: vpc-08cccbaf3a61d85bf
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
  ApiTaskDefinition:
    Properties:
      ContainerDefinitions:
      - Command:
        - us-east-1.compute.internal
        - laclientapi.local
        Essential: false
        Image: docker/ecs-searchdomain-sidecar:1.0
        LogConfiguration:
          LogDriver: awslogs
          Options:
            awslogs-group:
              Ref: LogGroup
            awslogs-region:
              Ref: AWS::Region
            awslogs-stream-prefix: laclientapi
        Name: Api_ResolvConf_InitContainer
      - DependsOn:
        - Condition: SUCCESS
          ContainerName: Api_ResolvConf_InitContainer
        Environment:
        - Name: DATABASE_URL
          Value: postgresql://postgres:postgres@database/laclient
        - Name: ROCKET_ADDRESS
          Value: 0.0.0.0
        - Name: ROCKET_ENV
          Value: release
        Essential: true
        Image: docker.io/outsidethecode/la-client-api:latest@sha256:9768ba65e9a2d1aa5055960cf90003f8181ed99ca85043d494a762538789b161
        LinuxParameters: {}
        LogConfiguration:
          LogDriver: awslogs
          Options:
            awslogs-group:
              Ref: LogGroup
            awslogs-region:
              Ref: AWS::Region
            awslogs-stream-prefix: laclientapi
        Name: api
        PortMappings:
        - ContainerPort: 8000
          HostPort: 8000
          Protocol: tcp
      Cpu: "256"
      ExecutionRoleArn:
        Ref: ApiTaskExecutionRole
      Family: laclientapi-api
      Memory: "512"
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities:
      - FARGATE
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
  ApiTaskExecutionRole:
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
          Condition: {}
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
        Version: 2012-10-17
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly
      Tags:
      - Key: com.docker.compose.project
        Value: laclientapi
      - Key: com.docker.compose.service
        Value: api
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  CloudMap:
    Properties:
      Description: Service Map for Docker Compose project laclientapi
      Name: laclientapi.local
      Vpc: vpc-08cccbaf3a61d85bf
    Type: AWS::ServiceDiscovery::PrivateDnsNamespace
  Cluster:
    Properties:
      ClusterName: laclientapi
      Tags:
      - Key: com.docker.compose.project
        Value: laclientapi
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
  DatabaseService:
    DependsOn:
    - DatabaseTCP5432Listener
    Properties:
      Cluster:
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - Cluster
        - Arn
      DeploymentConfiguration:
        MaximumPercent: 200
        MinimumHealthyPercent: 100
      DeploymentController:
        Type: ECS
      DesiredCount: 1
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      LoadBalancers:
      - ContainerName: database
        ContainerPort: 5432
        TargetGroupArn:
          Ref: DatabaseTCP5432TargetGroup
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
          SecurityGroups:
          - Ref: DefaultNetwork
          Subnets:
          - subnet-0bd97383cdf4d5896
          - subnet-0a52cf89f7c027b20
          - subnet-0ffafc731067a7d01
          - subnet-0de9ebed3a873fccf
          - subnet-00ae1e792af0e2e1d
          - subnet-0095a287059d86962
      PlatformVersion: 1.4.0
      PropagateTags: SERVICE
      SchedulingStrategy: REPLICA
      ServiceRegistries:
      - RegistryArn:
          Fn::GetAtt:
          - DatabaseServiceDiscoveryEntry
          - Arn
      Tags:
      - Key: com.docker.compose.project
        Value: laclientapi
      - Key: com.docker.compose.service
        Value: database
      TaskDefinition:
        Ref: DatabaseTaskDefinition
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
  DatabaseServiceDiscoveryEntry:
    Properties:
      Description: '"database" service discovery entry in Cloud Map'
      DnsConfig:
        DnsRecords:
        - TTL: 60
          Type: A
        RoutingPolicy: MULTIVALUE
      HealthCheckCustomConfig:
        FailureThreshold: 1
      Name: database
      NamespaceId:
        Ref: CloudMap
    Type: AWS::ServiceDiscovery::Service
  DatabaseTCP5432Listener:
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
      - ForwardConfig:
          TargetGroups:
          - TargetGroupArn:
              Ref: DatabaseTCP5432TargetGroup
        Type: forward
      LoadBalancerArn:
        Ref: LoadBalancer
      Port: 5432
      Protocol: TCP
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
  DatabaseTCP5432TargetGroup:
    Properties:
      Port: 5432
      Protocol: TCP
      Tags:
      - Key: com.docker.compose.project
        Value: laclientapi
      TargetType: ip
      VpcId: vpc-08cccbaf3a61d85bf
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
  DatabaseTaskDefinition:
    Properties:
      ContainerDefinitions:
      - Command:
        - us-east-1.compute.internal
        - laclientapi.local
        Essential: false
        Image: docker/ecs-searchdomain-sidecar:1.0
        LogConfiguration:
          LogDriver: awslogs
          Options:
            awslogs-group:
              Ref: LogGroup
            awslogs-region:
              Ref: AWS::Region
            awslogs-stream-prefix: laclientapi
        Name: Database_ResolvConf_InitContainer
      - DependsOn:
        - Condition: SUCCESS
          ContainerName: Database_ResolvConf_InitContainer
        Environment:
        - Name: POSTGRES_DB
          Value: laclient
        - Name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          Value: postgres
        - Name: POSTGRES_USER
          Value: postgres
        Essential: true
        Image: docker.io/library/postgres:latest@sha256:f1aaf6f8be5552bef66c5580efbd2942c37d7277cd0416ef4939fa34bf0baf31
        LinuxParameters: {}
        LogConfiguration:
          LogDriver: awslogs
          Options:
            awslogs-group:
              Ref: LogGroup
            awslogs-region:
              Ref: AWS::Region
            awslogs-stream-prefix: laclientapi
        Name: database
        PortMappings:
        - ContainerPort: 5432
          HostPort: 5432
          Protocol: tcp
      Cpu: "256"
      ExecutionRoleArn:
        Ref: DatabaseTaskExecutionRole
      Family: laclientapi-database
      Memory: "512"
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities:
      - FARGATE
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
  DatabaseTaskExecutionRole:
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
          Condition: {}
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
        Version: 2012-10-17
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly
      Tags:
      - Key: com.docker.compose.project
        Value: laclientapi
      - Key: com.docker.compose.service
        Value: database
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Default8000Ingress:
    Properties:
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      Description: api:8000/tcp on default network
      FromPort: 8000
      GroupId:
        Ref: DefaultNetwork
      IpProtocol: TCP
      ToPort: 8000
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
  Default80Ingress:
    Properties:
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      Description: nginx:80/tcp on default network
      FromPort: 80
      GroupId:
        Ref: DefaultNetwork
      IpProtocol: TCP
      ToPort: 80
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
  Default5432Ingress:
    Properties:
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      Description: database:5432/tcp on default network
      FromPort: 5432
      GroupId:
        Ref: DefaultNetwork
      IpProtocol: TCP
      ToPort: 5432
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
  DefaultNetwork:
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: laclientapi Security Group for default network
      Tags:
      - Key: com.docker.compose.project
        Value: laclientapi
      - Key: com.docker.compose.network
        Value: laclientapi_default
      VpcId: vpc-08cccbaf3a61d85bf
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  DefaultNetworkIngress:
    Properties:
      Description: Allow communication within network default
      GroupId:
        Ref: DefaultNetwork
      IpProtocol: "-1"
      SourceSecurityGroupId:
        Ref: DefaultNetwork
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
  LoadBalancer:
    Properties:
      LoadBalancerAttributes:
      - Key: load_balancing.cross_zone.enabled
        Value: "true"
      Scheme: internet-facing
      Subnets:
      - subnet-0bd97383cdf4d5896
      - subnet-0a52cf89f7c027b20
      - subnet-0ffafc731067a7d01
      - subnet-0de9ebed3a873fccf
      - subnet-00ae1e792af0e2e1d
      - subnet-0095a287059d86962
      Tags:
      - Key: com.docker.compose.project
        Value: laclientapi
      Type: network
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
  LogGroup:
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: /docker-compose/laclientapi
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
  NginxService:
    DependsOn:
    - NginxTCP80Listener
    - ApiService
    Properties:
      Cluster:
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - Cluster
        - Arn
      DeploymentConfiguration:
        MaximumPercent: 200
        MinimumHealthyPercent: 100
      DeploymentController:
        Type: ECS
      DesiredCount: 1
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      LoadBalancers:
      - ContainerName: nginx
        ContainerPort: 80
        TargetGroupArn:
          Ref: NginxTCP80TargetGroup
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
          SecurityGroups:
          - Ref: DefaultNetwork
          Subnets:
          - subnet-0bd97383cdf4d5896
          - subnet-0a52cf89f7c027b20
          - subnet-0ffafc731067a7d01
          - subnet-0de9ebed3a873fccf
          - subnet-00ae1e792af0e2e1d
          - subnet-0095a287059d86962
      PlatformVersion: 1.4.0
      PropagateTags: SERVICE
      SchedulingStrategy: REPLICA
      ServiceRegistries:
      - RegistryArn:
          Fn::GetAtt:
          - NginxServiceDiscoveryEntry
          - Arn
      Tags:
      - Key: com.docker.compose.project
        Value: laclientapi
      - Key: com.docker.compose.service
        Value: nginx
      TaskDefinition:
        Ref: NginxTaskDefinition
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
  NginxServiceDiscoveryEntry:
    Properties:
      Description: '"nginx" service discovery entry in Cloud Map'
      DnsConfig:
        DnsRecords:
        - TTL: 60
          Type: A
        RoutingPolicy: MULTIVALUE
      HealthCheckCustomConfig:
        FailureThreshold: 1
      Name: nginx
      NamespaceId:
        Ref: CloudMap
    Type: AWS::ServiceDiscovery::Service
  NginxTCP80Listener:
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
      - ForwardConfig:
          TargetGroups:
          - TargetGroupArn:
              Ref: NginxTCP80TargetGroup
        Type: forward
      LoadBalancerArn:
        Ref: LoadBalancer
      Port: 80
      Protocol: TCP
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
  NginxTCP80TargetGroup:
    Properties:
      Port: 80
      Protocol: TCP
      Tags:
      - Key: com.docker.compose.project
        Value: laclientapi
      TargetType: ip
      VpcId: vpc-08cccbaf3a61d85bf
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
  NginxTaskDefinition:
    Properties:
      ContainerDefinitions:
      - Command:
        - us-east-1.compute.internal
        - laclientapi.local
        Essential: false
        Image: docker/ecs-searchdomain-sidecar:1.0
        LogConfiguration:
          LogDriver: awslogs
          Options:
            awslogs-group:
              Ref: LogGroup
            awslogs-region:
              Ref: AWS::Region
            awslogs-stream-prefix: laclientapi
        Name: Nginx_ResolvConf_InitContainer
      - DependsOn:
        - Condition: SUCCESS
          ContainerName: Nginx_ResolvConf_InitContainer
        Essential: true
        Image: docker.io/library/nginx:latest@sha256:32da30332506740a2f7c34d5dc70467b7f14ec67d912703568daff790ab3f755
        LinuxParameters: {}
        LogConfiguration:
          LogDriver: awslogs
          Options:
            awslogs-group:
              Ref: LogGroup
            awslogs-region:
              Ref: AWS::Region
            awslogs-stream-prefix: laclientapi
        Name: nginx
        PortMappings:
        - ContainerPort: 80
          HostPort: 80
          Protocol: tcp
      Cpu: "256"
      ExecutionRoleArn:
        Ref: NginxTaskExecutionRole
      Family: laclientapi-nginx
      Memory: "512"
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities:
      - FARGATE
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
  NginxTaskExecutionRole:
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
          Condition: {}
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
        Version: 2012-10-17
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly
      Tags:
      - Key: com.docker.compose.project
        Value: laclientapi
      - Key: com.docker.compose.service
        Value: nginx
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
```

I am not sure what to do to pass the ECS health check. Any help is much appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: Port `8000` doesn't appear in the CloudFormation template. Something seems wrong, like the docker-compose file in your question isn't the one used to generate that CloudFormation template or something.

Comment: Also, are you aware that running a database on ECS Fargate means that all the data in your database will be wiped every time you deploy?

Comment: Thanks @MarkB. You are right, not sure why the template is not correct. I've re-generated the template using: `compose-ecs convert` and I updated the template above. I've also added nginx so that the health check get 200 when accessing http://localhost/.

What do you believe might be the issue? Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @MarkB I even tried to bypass the health check by adding: healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "exit 0"] to the api service but I am getting the same issue `ApiService ServiceSchedulerInitiated: Task failed ELB health checks in (target-group arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:821...:targetgroup/laclie-ApiTC-N...)`.

Comment: The health check you are editing with `CMD-SHELL` is the docker health check. That is totally separate from the target group health check.

Comment: Also, you added an entire extra container (nginx), running on port 80, which totally changes everything. I'm not sure you can even do that nginx proxy with the docker-compose ECS support. The target group in the cloudformation code isn't using that Nginx server at all.

Comment: You simply need to make sure that your API container returns 200 success when a GET request is sent to the `/` endpoint. If it returns another 2xx or 3xx status code, then you need to modify the target group health check settings to accept that code instead. If the health check needs to go against a different endpoint, then you need to update the target group to check against that endpoint.

Comment: Also note that, unfortunately the docker-compose ECS support is deprecated. I think it's actually being removed entirely next month. I highly recommend using something like Terraform to setup everything in AWS instead of docker-compose at this point.

Comment: Ok I'll try that option. Many thanks @MarkB for your help.